# Exception in Java for null values in lambda expression while filtering

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have an object, `Person`, which has two properties `Name` and `Status`. From a list of objects I hope to filter out the `Person` objects with a status of `In Progress`. Here is my code:

```
personList.stream().filter(
    t -> t.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(
        "In Progress")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But the code is throwing a `nullpointerexception` error. When I checked, I saw that a few of the objects with `In Progress` status had null values. How do we handle this in lambda?

Comment: You handle it juste like in any other code. It's better in this case to do "In Progress".equalsIgnoreCase(t.getStatus())

Comment: The real question is what you want to happen when status is null. Do you want to filter those rows out? Include them? Fail with a meaningful message? Return false from the method?

Null is an exceptional condition that requires thought and not some technical trick to ignore. If you don't want to put in that kind of thought, you should avoid letting status be null in the first place.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just reverse the 2 "operands" of the `equals` method:

```
"In Progress".equalsIgnoreCase(t.getStatus())
```

This way since `"In Progress"` can never be null, there won't be an NPE!

Comment: Yoda strikes back. Classic!

Comment: This, _this_, and **this**.  I have lost count the number of times I have fixed Java libraries' NPE (public and not) by merely using Yoda conditions.  I wish there were a way to evangelize this just a bit more.

Comment: @EelLee back strikes Yoda

Comment: Or always use Objects.equals() instead of instance.equals()

Comment: @hunteke But you shouldn't blindly use them.

Comment: This hides the fact that there might be a `person` with an invalid status. [@TheRock3t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274061/therock3t) gave a better answer.

Comment: @hunteke Yoda equality is terse but it removes not-null validation that should probably be there most of the time. Most variables in most programs should never be null. In the few cases where a variable can be null, yoda equality is handy, but it's a special tool for a special case.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret Perhaps; I'm always willing to concede to other's lived experience. However, my experience has ~never needed this sort of null check. Am I just lucky that I haven't been bitten in ~13 years? Maybe. But I stand by my point of the countless times I have fixed libraries and other code by Yoda conditions. Sometimes, the compiler caught the issue, other times it was logic exploitation like this, etc. In this case, I argue it's the correct thing to do, not the wrong thing. The sole condition is if `t` is `"In Progress"`. But that's all I can faithfully argue here: this case.

Comment: @hunteke Fair enough. And conditionals are not the right place for null checks. But generally I like to program in a way that avoids nulls and is hostile to nulls so that the accidental null gets caught quickly. Perhaps you have a different style.

Answer (score 25):

Try filtering out objects with null statuses

```
personList
  .stream()
  .filter(t -> t.getStatus() != null)
  .filter(t -> t.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("In Progress"))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is better than Sweeper's answer because it makes explicit what you want to happen to null values.

Answer (score 12):

You can chain/merge `filter`ing conditions to operate on non-null values with short-circuited conditions as:

```
personList.stream()
          .filter(t -> t.getStatus() != null && t.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("In Progress"))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Spoken from the nullpointer himself!  And remember kids, order matters!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming for `status = null`, you won't select it. Then you can use `"In Progress".equalsIgnoreCase(t.getStatus())` to avoid any possible `null` value in your status.

In whole,

```
personList.stream()
    .filter(t -> "In Progress".equalsIgnoreCase(t.getStatus()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```